# Fullcalendar: How to hide repeating Background-Events from the past?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am adding the events like that:

```
events: [

    {
        title: '',
        start: '2014-09-01T17:00:00',
        end: '2014-09-01T21:00:00',
        dow: [1], // repeat same weekday
        rendering: 'background', 
        color: '#6BA5C2'
    },
    {
        title: '',
        start: '2014-09-02T17:00:00',
        end: '2014-09-02T21:00:00',
        dow: [2], // repeat same weekday
        rendering: 'background', 
        color: '#6BA5C2'
    },
    {
        title: '',
        start: '2014-09-03T17:00:00',
        end: '2014-09-03T21:00:00',
        dow: [3], // repeat same weekday
        rendering: 'background', 
        color: '#6BA5C2'
    },

    {
        title: '',
        start: '2014-09-04T17:00:00',
        end: '2014-09-04T21:00:00',
        dow: [4], // repeat same weekday
        rendering: 'background', 
        // color: '#0A0'
        color: '#6BA5C2'
    },
    {
        title: '',
        start: '2014-09-05T17:00:00',
        end: '2014-09-05T21:00:00',
        dow: [5], // repeat same weekday
        rendering: 'background', 
        color: '#6BA5C2'
    },
```

Which gives me (see blue events, ignore the red events and the gray backgrounds):

[image: fullcal]

By using `dow` the events get shown on all week views. However, I want to hide them from the past. So today is Thu, 7 Jan, and I want to hide/remove all from the past.

And also the new property [businessHours](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/businessHours/) is only repeated all day.

Do I have to add single events instead of using `dow` or is there another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide events being shown in the past, use the eventRender callback and call hide on any with an earlier date that have a rendering property value of 'background'. The exact logic regarding dates can differ and is up to you. The below example compares the start of the event to the current time. The fiddle uses fixed dates but is the same idea.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j70cvucs/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        ...
        eventRender: function(event, element){
            if (event.rendering == 'background' && event.start <  moment("2015-02-13")){
            element.hide();
          }
        },
        ...
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am also hiding the today's background event now, using `if(event.rendering == 'background' && event.start <= moment().endOf('day')) { element.hide(); }`. Great to see that the solution is not as difficult as I expected. Working example: http://www.matheboss.de/booking?userid=134